# twittet oauth problems: can't do verify_credentials api call

Tags: perl, twitter, twitter-oauth

Trying to use OAuth for user authenticating via **OAuth 1.0A**

I do successfully get request_tokens, i do successfully get oauth_token and oauth_secret.
Then, i am supposed to perform api call as described [over there](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554689/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3a-account%C2%A0verify_credentials).

I perform get-request to url **api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.xml**
with authorization header:

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="zqOQIgnviRjNDuGIdHAA",oauth_nonce="1997904",oauth_signature="aSf2zj8xfjXcN9z%2B04eOwFd8fKk%3D",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1291981333",oauth_token="jxmgnF4m2HB7IP9RbylyyF7gaZuRXj8YF1eVUIDSLrk",oauth_version="1.0"
```

and get:

```
401 Unauthorized <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <error>Could not authenticate with OAuth.</error>
  <request>/1/account/verify_credentials.xml</request>
</hash>
```

I triple-checked everything: access token, access_token_secret, signature generation, etc, etc - no luck.

But, i suppose, cause i managed to get access token, that's not twitter problem.
I'm using Net::OAuth perl module.

Can anybody help me, please? What authentication is twitter talking about? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check your system clock.

Comment: clock was ok, seems it's some code problems, though i've rewritten everything using Net::Twitter::Lite and it works nicely. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should be asking this question on the Twitter developer mailing list. They do a great job of debugging OAuth problems. You will get right to Twitter engineers. Include the level of details you have here.

http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk

Comment: thanks to all, i didnt figure out what was the problem, fixed it via rewriting code using Net::Twitter::Lite by M. Mims.